# Differences between git remote update and fetch?

Tags: git, git-remote, git-fetch

Is `git remote update` the equivalent of `git fetch`?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

**UPDATE: more information!**

I should have done this from the start: I grepped the Git release notes in Git's Git repo (so meta!)

```
grep --color=always -R -C30 fetch Documentation/RelNotes/* | less
```

Then I did a `less` search for `--all`, and this is what I found under the [release notes for Git version 1.6.6](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v1.8.3.2/Documentation/RelNotes/1.6.6.txt#L162-166):

> `git fetch` learned `--all` and `--multiple` options, to run fetch from many repositories, and `--prune` option to remove remote tracking branches that went stale.  These make `git remote update` and `git remote prune` less necessary (there is no plan to remove `remote update` nor `remote prune`, though).

Version 1.6.6 wasn't released until [December 23rd, 2009](https://github.com/git/git/commit/902f235378cb2b2f6dd5dd664b9630c95321f0ae), and the Original Poster asked his question on December 6th 2009.

So as you can see from the release notes, the authors of Git were aware of the fact that the `git remote update` command functionality was being duplicated somewhat by `git fetch`, but they decided not to remove it, maybe for backward compatibility with existing scripts and programs, or maybe because it's just too much work and there are higher priority items.

---

**Original answer with more details**

[xenoterracide's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1856504/456814) is 3.5 years old now, and Git has gone through several versions since then (it has gone from [v1.6.5.5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aa031314bf8189a15290d5bd0d85fa2a0307ceb7) to v1.8.3.2 as of this writing), and looking at the ***current*** documentation for [`git remote update`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html) and [`git fetch`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html), it looks like they ***both can perform basically the same function of fetching new commits from multiple remotes***, given the right options and arguments.

#### Fetching all remotes

One way to fetch multiple remotes is with the `--all` flag:

```
git fetch --all
```

This will fetch from all of your configured remotes, assuming that you don't have `remote.<name>.skipFetchAll` set for them:

> If true, this remote will be skipped by default when updating using [git-fetch(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html) or the update subcommand of [git-remote(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html). — [git-config documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html)

This would be equivalent to using

```
git remote update
```

without specifying any remote group to fetch, and also not having `remotes.default` set in your repo configuration, and also that none of your remotes have `remote.<name>.skipDefaultUpdate` set to true.

The [current 1.8.3.2 documentation for Git's configuration](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v1.8.3.2/Documentation/config.txt) doesn't mention the `remotes.default` setting, but I consulted The Almighty Google about it and found this helpful explanation from [Mislav Marohnić](https://mislav.net/2010/07/git-tips/):

```
$ git config remotes.default 'origin mislav staging'
$ git remote update

# fetches remotes "origin", "mislav", and "staging"
```

> You can define a default list of remotes to be fetched by the `remote update` command. These can be remotes from your teammates, trusted community members of an opensource project, or similar.

So presumably, if you have `remotes.default` set, and not all of your remotes are listed in it, then `git remote update` won't fetch all remotes that your repo is "aware" of.

As for the `remote.<name>.skipDefaultUpdate` setting, [the Git docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) explain it thusly:

> If true, this remote will be skipped by default when updating using [git-fetch(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html) or the update subcommand of [git-remote(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html).

#### Fetching a specified group of remotes

Instead of fetching all remotes, both `fetch` and `remote update` allow you to specify multiple remotes and groups of remotes to fetch:

```
git fetch [<options>] <group>
git fetch --multiple [<options>] [(<repository> | <group>)…]
```

`git fetch [<options>] <group>` allows you to fetch multiple remotes that are part of a group (to borrow another example from [Mislav](https://mislav.net/2010/07/git-tips/)):

```
$ git config remotes.mygroup 'remote1 remote2 ...'
$ git fetch mygroup
```

`git fetch --multiple` allows you to specify several repositories and repository groups to fetch at once (from [the docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html)):

> Allow several `<repository>` and `<group>` arguments to be specified. No `<refspec>s` may be specified.

**Ambiguity in `git remote update` documentation**

The [synopsis for `git remote update`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html) specifies that the command syntax is as follows:

```
git remote [-v | --verbose] update [-p | --prune] [(<group> | <remote>)…]
```

Notice the last part, `[(<group> | <remote>)…]`?  The trailing dots `...` imply that you can specify multiple groups and remotes with the command, which would mean it behaves in the same way as `git fetch --multiple`...see how the syntax between the two is so similar?

However, in the same document, the explanation for the `update` command says nothing about specifying multiple group and remote arguments, only that it

> Fetch[es] updates for a named set of remotes in the repository as defined by `remotes.<group>`.

So it's unclear if `git remote update` works identically to `git fetch --multiple` with regard to specifying multiple individual remotes and multiple remote groups.

#### Fetching a single remote

Finally, everyone knows the simple case of fetching a single remote:

```
git fetch <remote>
```

It might be the case that you can also use

```
git remote update <remote>
```

to do the same thing, but as I mentioned in the previous section, the documentation for `git remote update` is unclear about whether it's possible to fetch anything other than a single ***group*** of remotes with the command.

#### Wrapup

As I've explained, `git fetch` and `git remote update` behave similarly with regard to fetching from multiple remotes.  They share similar syntax and arguments, though `git fetch` is shorter, so people probably find it easier to type and use.

It may be the case that `git remote update` can't be used to fetch just a single remote like with `git fetch`, but as I've pointed out, the documentation doesn't make this clear.

**Aside**

The duplication in functionality between Git porcelain commands, exemplified by `git fetch` and `git remote update` above, is not unique.  I've noticed a similar situation with [`git rebase --onto`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html) and [`git cherry-pick`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html), in that both can take a range of commits to patch onto a new base commit.

I guess that as Git has evolved over the years, some functionality was (inevitably?) duplicated, perhaps sometimes as a convenience for end-users (for example, it's simpler to pass a range to `cherry-pick`, than to pass a single commit over and over to pick a range).  Apparently `cherry-pick` didn't always accept a range of commits, as explained in the [v1.7.2 release notes](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v1.8.3.2/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.2.txt#L50-53):

> `git cherry-pick` learned to pick a range of commits (e.g. `cherry-pick A..B` and `cherry-pick --stdin`), so did `git revert`; these do not support the nicer sequencing control `rebase [-i]` has, though.

Comment: FYI: `git rebase` is like `mv` and `git cherry-pick` is like `cp`. The `--onto` switch does not change that. You can get a copy-effect with `git rebase` only if you specify SHA1 values, otherwise your branch will be moved!

Answer (score 145):

Yes and no. `git remote update` fetches from all remotes, not just one.

Without looking at the code to see if `remote update` is just a shell script (possible) it, basically, runs fetch for each remote. `git fetch` can be much more granular.

Comment: You can configure which remotes to fetch when running `git remote update`, see git-remote manpage.

Comment: Incidentally, `git remote` is not a shell script, but it spawns `git fetch` during a `remote update`.

Comment: Is there an equivalent `git fetch` command options for a `git remote update`?

Comment: @tuler Yes: it is `git fetch --all`