# Can't see remote branch

Tags: git

I'm stil learning git and not sure how some basic things work. I created a local branch by doing:

```
git branch AppStore
```

I can't remember exactly how I pushed this branch to github.com, but I can see MyBranch on the repository.  When I do

```
git branch -a
```

I see this:

```
  ARC
* AppStore
  Refactoring
  Release3
  master
  remotes/origin/AppStore
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
```

There are more remotes listed as well.  So from my computer where I created the branch, I see the AppStore branch.  However, none of my coworkers can.  When we tried a

```
git pull origin AppStore
```

It grabbed the changes.  But when we tried

```
git checkout AppStore 
or
git checkout origin AppStore
```

We were not able to.  What are we missing?  Thanks!

Edit:

I did try this according to VonC's answer:

```
git push --set-upstream origin AppStore
```

After putting in my credentials, I get:

```
Branch AppStore set up to track remote branch AppStore from origin.
Everything up-to-date
```

But my coworkers still cannot see the branch :-.

Comment: Are you sure you are all referring to the same thing when you say "origin"? You can have a look with `git remote -v`

Comment: A very similar problem - [Git: Cannot see new remote branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12730344/465053).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to publish your branch on your upstream repo, while tracking it locally (making sure your local branch keep in synch with that new remote branch: see "[What is a tracking branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693588/git-what-is-a-tracking-branch/4697054#4697054)")

```
git push --set-upstream origin AppStore
```

---

As mentioned in the comments, the other developers need to fetch what has been pushed (included the new branch).
A git fetch origin is one way, but if you are unsure of the name of the remote repo, a [`git remote update`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856499/git-remote-update) works just fine.

That will update their remote branches, but won't create a local branch of the same name, as detailed in "[Track all remote git branches as local branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379081/track-all-remote-git-branches-as-local-branches)".

Comment: So I thought I did that before, and I ran that command again.  My coworkers still cannot see my branch.  I edited my post for the details.

Comment: @Crystal After they `git fetch`, they still need to checkout that remote branch as a local branch in their own local repo: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379081/track-all-remote-git-branches-as-local-branches/6300386#6300386: it is an answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379081/track-all-remote-git-branches-as-local-branches which illustrates that you don't see by default new remote branches.

Comment: So after the git remote update was used, I could then see the remote AppStore branch.  I don't remember having to call update before, but at least it works now!  Thx!

Comment: So after I push a branch, do they always need to git fetch.

Comment: @Crystal: yes: `git fetch` is mandatory for other local repos to fetch from a "blessed" remote repo. I have edited the answer to include that step.

Comment: `git remote update` refreshed `git branch -r` such that I can now see my coworker's branch.

Comment: `git remote update` was all my coworker needed to do and it worked just fine for updating the list of existing branches. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

When you do a `git branch xyz` it creates a branch `xyz` on your local machine. Generally you create a new branch off the `master branch` so that it has the `master's code`. After creating the branch `xyz`, you make changes and then you have to `git push origin xyz` for the branch to be visible on `github`.

Doing `git branch -a` will show your branches in your machine. Till you `push` your branch you cannot find it on the remote repo.

Comment: its because they have nothing better to do than put other people down @noMAD .