# git does not show up a newly created branch Gerrit Code Review UI

Tags: git, gerrit

Through Gerrit Web UI I created a branch from one of old commits in the commit chain

A previous version of code repository exists locally.

I make a `git pull` command to update my local repo.

I try to run `git branch -a` and this newly created branch does not show up.

However, if I clone this repo elsewhere all branches show up as desired.

Can anyone please throw some light on this?

**Update:**

I tried running `git ls-remote` as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12762922/git-cannot-see-new-remote-branch). This displays the newly created head. However, `git branch -a` does not show updated status of the repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still do not understand the reason why this would happen.
However one way is to `clone` the repo elsewhere...this fixed my problem.

If for some reason `clone` is **not** an option for you, delete the remote refs and add it back again like this:

```
git remote -v

#will display list of all...

<remote name> <remote url/ or ssh alias(if configured)>
<remote name> <remote url/ or ssh alias(if configured)>
.....

git remote rm <remote name>

# add the same remote again
git remote add <remote name> <remote url or ssh alias(if already configured)>

# now pull 
git pull <remote name>
```

Answer (score 2):

`git pull <remote> or git pull` command will only update your local repo but when you run `git branch` command, the branch created from Gerrit will not show up. You will need to run the following to command:

```
$git check -b branch_name --track origin/branch_name
```

where `branch_name` is the branch name created in Gerrit.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bug. This is indeed the case but you can actually do a `git checkout new-branch` and after this the branch will show up when you do `git branch -a`

This seems a bit strange as you can not see the branch but you can checkout the branch. I assume you also saw the `[new branch] test-branch -> origin->test-branch` when you did `git pull`

Comment: thanks for your answer...you are right I did not see that message `[new branch]...` on `git pull`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this command before others, and the branch will show up:

```
git fetch origin <branch_name>
```