# Backup git repos, git fetch vs git remote update

Tags: git, github

I want to backup git repos using this SO answer: [Backup a GitHub repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251713/backup-of-github-repo)

```
git clone --mirror git://github.com/user/project.git
git fetch
```

The only difference is I am using `git fetch` instead of `git remote update`

Are there any drawback of the two commands? (from the complete backup point of view, e.g. backup all tags, branches)

Comment: Check this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856499/differences-between-git-remote-update-and-fetch

Comment: @Danstahr, thanks, so assume my only remote is github, so both commands are the same?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, unless you setup a specific configuration, `git remote updates` runs a `git fetch` against all your remotes.

The [man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) states

```
update
Fetch updates for a named set of remotes in the repository as defined
by remotes.<group>. If a named group is not specified on the command 
line, the configuration parameter remotes.default will be used; if 
remotes.default is not defined, all remotes which do not have the 
configuration parameter remote.<name>.skipDefaultUpdate set to true 
will be updated. (See git-config[1]).
```

In your case, if you didn't define any `remotes.<group>` nor a `remotes.default`, and if your only remote is github, running `git remote update` or `git fetch` is completely equivalent.