# Fetching simultaneously from several git repositories

Tags: git, fetch

I've got a couple of git repositories, each of them has several remotes named `public_<user>`.

I'd like to fetch simultaneously from every remote for all repositories.

I'd already discovered ([myrepos](https://github.com/joeyh/myrepos.git)) but this script only seams to work for `origin` remotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `git remote update` command will perform a `fetch` operation on all remotes for a given repository:

```
$ git remote
larsks
origin
$ git remote update
Fetching origin
remote: Reusing existing pack: 1, done.
remote: Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (1/1), done.
From https://github.com/teythoon/afew
   7317eb0..50db012  master     -> origin/master
Fetching larsks
From github.com:larsks/afew
```

If you wanted to automatically run this across a collection of git
repositories, you could do something like this:

```
$ find * -maxdepth 1 -name .git -execdir git remote update \;
```

This finds everything containing a `.git` directory and then runs `git remote update` in the parent of the `.git` directory.

To find all *bare* repositories, you could do something like:

```
$ find * -maxdepth 1 -name index -execdir git remote update \;
```

That is, look for the `index` file instead of the `.git` directory.

If you wanted to target all submodules, you can use the `git submodule foreach` command:

```
$ find * -maxdepth 1 -name .git -execdir \
  git submodule foreach git remote update \;
```

If you wanted to combine this all into a single command:

```
$ find * -maxdepth 1 -name .git -execdir \
  sh -c 'git remote update; git submodule foreach git remote update' \;
```

Comment: Sounds great. How would I alter the script if I wanted to find (a) all bare repositories or (b) target all sub-modules?

Comment: I've updated the answer with some additional examples.

Comment: Thanks. I think this should be exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for the `--all` flag:

```
git fetch --all
```

Based on a quick glance at the script you linked, it seems like that script will accept this flag and pass it on to git for each of your repositories.

Comment: Is there a difference between `git fetch --all` and `git remote update`? Seams to me they both do the same.

Comment: As best I can tell, no. There's some discussion and history here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856499/differences-between-git-remote-update-and-fetch

Answer (score 0):

[git forward](https://github.com/wolf/git-forward) fetches, prunes, and fast-forwards any number of tracking branches over any number of remotes at once.  It's great for an integrator who's following many remotes/branches at once.